# Scaling Azure Postgres: Specified Availability Zone not supported in this region

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I try to scale (provide more Cores) to my Azure Postgres DB (Flexible Server). No matter which size I choose, I always get the same error: "Specified Availability Zone not supported in this region."

The DB is deployed to Sweden Central. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-region), Sweden Central supports availability zones. The VM Sizes I tried are also available in that region.

Does anyone has any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: "Specified Availability Zone not supported in this region."

We also tried in our Environment with **`Region: Sweden Central`** we also got same error  but when we tried with **`Region: East US`** the **database is scaled from 2 cores to 8 cores successfully.**

You can raise support ticket to Microsoft from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) for more asistance on this.

Comment: You seem to be right. It seems to be a sweden problem. I was able to scale the DB in West Europe too. I already opened a ticket